# Could not find support-annotations.jar

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso

I'm trying to follow the instructions on android testing step 7
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/#6

cloned the repo: `git clone https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing.git -b step-7`

Even though I remove every reference to support-annotations, gradle gives the same error and stops:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not find support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1).
  Searched in the following locations:      file:/C:/Users/UserName/Documents/android_studio/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.1.1/support-annotations-23.1.1.jar
```

`build.gradle` file:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.android.testing.notes"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        }

        buildTypes {
            debug {
                // Run code coverage reports by default on debug builds.
                // testCoverageEnabled = true
            }
        }

        // If you need to add more flavors, consider using flavor dimensions.
        productFlavors {
            mock {
                applicationIdSuffix = ".mock"
            }
            prod {

            }
        }

        // Remove mockRelease as it's not needed.
        android.variantFilter { variant ->
            if(variant.buildType.name.equals('release')
                    && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('mock')) {
                variant.setIgnore(true);
            }
        }

        // Always show the result of every unit test, even if it passes.
        testOptions.unitTests.all {
            testLogging {
                events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     Dependency versions are defined in the top level build.gradle file. This helps keeping track of
     all versions in a single place. This improves readability and helps managing project complexity.
     */
    dependencies {
        // App's dependencies, including test
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
        compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
        compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
        compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
        compile "com.google.guava:guava:$rootProject.guavaVersion"
        compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glideVersion"
        compile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"

        // Dependencies for local unit tests
        testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
        testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
        testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$rootProject.ext.hamcrestVersion"
        testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"
        testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"

        // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
        androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion"
        androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion"

        // Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
        androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
        androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
        androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
    }

    /*
    Resolves dependency versions across test and production APKs, specifically, transitive
    dependencies. This is required since Espresso internally has a dependency on support-annotations.
    */
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    }

    /*
    All direct/transitive dependencies shared between your test and production APKs need to be
    excluded from the test APK! This is necessary because both APKs will contain the same classes. Not
    excluding these dependencies from your test configuration will result in an dex pre-verifier error
    at runtime. More info in this tools bug: (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192497)
    */
    configurations.compile.dependencies.each { compileDependency ->
        println "Excluding compile dependency: ${compileDependency.getName()}"
        configurations.androidTestCompile.dependencies.each { androidTestCompileDependency ->
            configurations.androidTestCompile.exclude module: "${compileDependency.getName()}"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cloned the project and was able to build & run it successfully.  What are you doing when you get the error?

Comment: Yes, Finally I was able to compile the project. 
It was android studio 2.1. Amazingly giving me the same error for all projects, whether they are looking for support-annotations or not.
I revalidated the cache, updated all SDK repositories. Restarted android studio. and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the dependencies:

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services,extra-google-m2repository

gradle dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

update android support repository package