# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' - Dependencies are in Module level build.gradle already

Tags: android, gradle

Yes, I m having this Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' problem again.

I checked that I have :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

... in the {root}/build.gradle file

and having ...

```
dependencies {
    // App's dependencies, including test
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:$rootProject.guavaVersion"
    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glideVersion"
    ...
}
```

... in the app/build.gradle file.

In fact, I am trying to get the Google example from [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html#1) to work.  It is not working out of box, having this issue.

The gradle version is: 2.1.0

The gradle wrapper version is: **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip**

Thanks in advance, this is burning me.

Comment: Please provide a sample project on GitHub that demonstrates the issue. The code you show here looks correct. We'd need to see how you organize and structure the code to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be your syntax is wrong in `build.gradle`(App Level) for adding Dependencies. In android studio, gradle supports Groovy based language. Just try to remove double colon(""). For ex :

**Try this** -

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion'
```

**instead of**

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing compile " "

with ' '

Comment: Thank you guys so much ~!  It works ~  I really should pick this up earlier. Thanks again. @OnkarNene

Comment: @OnkarNene, Hi guys, sorry.  It doesn't work.

compile ' ' and compile " " are BOTH VALID syntax. 

compile " " allows you  to use :${variableName} for variable look-up and replacement.  

Therefore, although, yes, change **compile " "** to **compile ' '** compiles, it's actually a work around rather than solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @OnkarNene and @YashJain for your suggestion, unfortunately it's not solving the problem.

compile ' ' and compile " " are BOTH VALID syntax.

compile " " allows you  to use :${variableName} for variable look-up and replacement.

I found my solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097026/could-not-find-support-annotations-jar).  The reason for this problem is when I upgrade my Android Studio, it somehow mixed up my existing repository (sorry, still not fully understand how Android Studio / Gradle / Gradle Wrapper's repository works), I solve the problem by force clean the repository, then gradle builds again.

Many thanks ~